# SQL Database Model: FOOD and INGREDIENTS tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: FOOD and INGREDIENTS. I want to select all ingredients that are necessary to make certain food.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
select NAME from INGREDIENTS
 where ID in (select ING1_ID, ING2_ID, ING3_ID from FOOD where NAME = 'Meat soup')
```

That obviously doesn't work as I need to pass a string of comma separated IDs in the "in" sub-select query. I was looking into converting list of column values into a string and there are some solutions out there but I started to think that maybe I'm over-complicating this and my database model is wrong.

**FOOD Table:**

```
ID      | NAME          | ING1_ID  | ING2_ID  | ING3_ID
--------+---------------+----------+----------+--------
1       | Meat soup     | 1        | 2        | 3
2       | Pasta Bolo    | 3        | 4        | 5
3       | Chicken salad | 2        | 4        | 5
```

**INGREDIENTS Table:**

```
ID      | NAME          
--------+-----------
1       | pasta     
2       | onion   
3       | oil 
4       | paprika 
5       | chicken 
6       | cucumber
```

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many dishes have more than three ingredients, and when you're searching, you don't care about whether a given ingredient is #1 or #2 or #3.

So a better model is

```
FOOD
id | name
1  | meat soup


INGREDIENTS
id | name 
1  | meat  

FOOD_INGREDIENTS
food_id | ingredients_id
1       | 1
```

Now your query is just

```
select i.name from ingredients i, food f, food_ingredients fi
where fi.food_id = f.id
and fi.ingredients_id = i.id
and f.name = "meat soup"
```

The "food_ingredients" table is often called a "join table".  Another nice thing about a join table is that you can add information that's specific to the particular inclusion of an ingredient in a kind of food (such as amount, or how it should be prepared).

Answer (score 3):

Your problems stem from the fact that you do not have a normalized data model.

You should redesign into something like this:

**FOOD table:**

- FoodID
- Name

**INGREDIENTS table:**

- IngID
- Name

**FOOD2INGREDIENTS table:**

- FoodID
- IngID
- (adding quantity here would make a lot of sense)

Once such a redesign had been made you could get what you want simply by querying:

```
SELECT i.ID, I.Name 
FROM Ingredients I 
 INNER JOIN Food2Ingredients F2I 
 ON I.IngID = F2I.IngID
WHERE
  F2I.FoodID = :foodid;
```

Comment: Is the colon before foodid intentional or is it a typo?

Comment: Sorry - it's a oracle habit. Please read it as 'insery your foodid here'.

Answer (score 2):

As long as all your recipes are so impoverished as to require exactly three ingredients, then you can resolve the problem with the original query by writing:

```
SELECT Name FROM Ingredients
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ING1_ID FROM Food WHERE Name = 'Meat soup'
              UNION
              SELECT ING2_ID FROM Food WHERE Name = 'Meat soup'
              UNION
              SELECT ING3_ID FROM Food WHERE Name = 'Meat soup'
             )
```

However, I think [JacobM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237/jacobm) and [Kerbocat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452237/kerbocat) are onto the right idea with the database redesign, and your sense that there was something wrong with your database design is to be commended.  Note that if you need a recipe with 4 (or more) ingredients, you face a disaster with the current design (for example, because you have to edit all the existing SQL which includes multi-way UNION operations like the one shown above), but the redesigned schemas wouldn't even notice.

Comment: The model I posted here is simplified but your and other commenters' point is very valid. I haven't used join tables before so that's the piece of the puzzle I was missing here. Thanks!